# ShowDialog() memory leak workaround

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, showdialog

In my company's enterprise solution, I am going through and cleaning out as many memory leaks as I can.

We have a BaseCaptureForm which is inherited by many other forms (for example, RecommendationCaptureForm). Throughout the system (for example) this RecommendationCaptureForm is called modally (ShowDialog()). Now as far as I know, when forms are opened modally they should be wrapped in a using statement or disposed of when done.

There is a dispose method in the BaseCaptureForm which is never hit. I put in a finalizer and it is never hit as well. ANTS Memory Profiler shows that all these forms are retained in memory.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can go about disposing these capture forms (which aren't open for all that long) in order to stop leaking memory? There are millions of ShowDialog calls throughout the system and I was wondering if anyone else has hit this problem?

**Edit**
To clarify, is there something I can do in the BaseCaptureForm to automatically dispose itself once closed? I cannot go through all the ShowDialog() calls in hoping of disposing them.
Calling the dispose method in the OnClosed event of the form causes a nasty flicker.

Comment: So, they *are* wrapped in a `using` statement? I don't really understand what you're trying to work around.

Comment: Well no, they aren't wrapped in a using statement as sometimes they are needed within a different scope. I also cannot go through millions of ShowDialog() calls to try and possibly dispose them.

Comment: So you want a workaround to dispose objects without ever calling their `Dispose` method (either manually, or with a `using` statement)? Sorry, not going to happen. Computers only do what you tell them to.

Comment: Are you sure there's a memory leak? Perhaps the GC just hasn't run for a while? Or maybe you're holding onto references to the forms in some data structure somewhere?

Comment: Cody obviously that is the case, and normally such things are thought of. But obviously people who wrote the majority of the system I am working on did not know that ShowDialog does not dispose of things properly.

Comment: Yes, occasionally programmers make mistakes. Your job as a maintenance programmer is to fix those mistakes. There's no miracle cure. You either let the GC collector take care of it eventually (and suffer the consequences) or you go through the code and fix it.

Comment: Nick, ANTS Memory Profiler forces a complete garbage collection. The system's capture forms all still reside in memory and the one specific one I am checking doesn't have any strange references that are being held onto. The garbage collector does not even get around to cleaning up when the form goes out of scope.

Comment: Well, do you want to fix the memory leak or not?  If you do, you need to ensure that each of these forms is disposed of properly.  If you say you can't do that, then you'll have to live with the leak.  You can't have the form dispose of itself; usually you need it around after it closes to read values it collected for you back out.

Comment: @Dylan: If the object is being kept ineligible for collection, then it's either pinned or rooted. If it's pinned, the memory profiler will tell you this and it should be easy to find out what pins it. If it's rooted, you can see the chain of references back up to the application root that is keeping it alive.

Comment: Any chance you could profile the application to figure out which `ShowDialog` calls are made most often? Your time would be best spent fixing leaks that are exercised daily than the leaks that are exercised monthly.

Comment: I dont think it would be an option to dispose the form once closed. What if you are using properties that are set on the form after it has been closed? Even accessing the property DialogResult after the form has been closed would then break. I think the best idea with this one is to go through the entire solution and fix up every ShowDialog call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this. What you have is bad code, and that bad code has to be corrected just like all other bad code: by fixing it and replacing it with *good* code. There are no band-aids to apply here; the band-aid is the finalizer of the `Form` calling `Dispose()`, which is never *guaranteed* to happen. If the object is ineligible for collection, then ANTS Memory Profiler will show you what's holding onto a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you use the forms after they have been closed (*), you can call Dispose() from within the FormClosed event handler.

I don't see the "nasty flicker" you refer to, one thing you might try is to set `this.Visible = false` in the FormClosed event handler.

(*) You may be safe as long as you are not exposing any controls or properties of controls via publicly-visible properties or methods of your form.  One way to avoid this is to implement such public properties with backing fields, and copy any data from controls into these backing fields before the form is closed.

Without seeing code it's difficult to see if this would be realistic in your scenario. And to be honest I'd be inclined to bite the bullet and clean up the calls by adding `using` statements.

Answer (score 1):

if dispose of the dialog is never called this can be an indicator of an exception which is thrown inside your form. Take a look at this [blogpost](http://www.reflectionit.nl/Blog/PermaLink7a2db2fc-eff3-4ad0-9e8c-2a8392a60c29.aspx).

Have you implemented the ["Ms Dispose Pattern"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28VS.90%29.aspx)?
Which can even help with your solution. Maybe you can provide some code?

Hope this can be a help for you...

Comment: It can also be a sign of **never calling the `Dispose` method**. Someone has to call it, whether it's the programmer explicitly or the garbage collector.

Comment: That is true. But in some cases **it looks** like it has been called. As described in the __blogpost__ above.

Comment: @Cody: Just to be clear here, **the garbage collector does not call `Dispose()`**. The garbage collector only calls finalizers.

Comment: @70sCommander: That's what `using` blocks are for, as the OP describes.

Comment: @Adam: I know that. But this is not the **focus** of my reply. I want to told him that it might be a solution if he checks for exceptions in the modal dialog. And a `dispose` call afterwards may not be called!

Comment: @70sCommander: That may be, but you aren't answering the OP's question. This is not a matter of his code calling `Dipose()` but it not being called at runtime; the original code does not have a call to `Dispose()` (or to anything else that would call `Dispose()`, like a `using` block). This should be, at most, a comment to the original question, since it doesn't answer anything that's being asked.